# custom query of custom post type by initial leter

Tags: php, wordpress

What I am trying to do is list a custom post type by the initial letter of the title. I have tried a few code examples but I cant seem to get it to fully function the way I want it. Here is some of the code that I have tried and manipulated to no avail.

```
 <div class="col-md-6"><!-- #### COLUMN #### -->

                <!-- ############################################## -->
                <!-- ############### PAGE TITLE T ################# -->
                <!-- ############################################## -->

                <p class="f_header">PAGE TITLE T</p>

                <?php

                $args = array(

                    'post_type'             => 'movies',
                    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => TRUE,
                    'substring_where'       => 'T',

                    );

                    function restrict_by_first_letter( $where, $qry ) {
                      global $wpdb;
                      $sub = $qry->get('substring_where');
                      if (!empty($sub)) {
                        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
                          " AND SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->movies}.movies_title, 1, 1 ) = %s ",
                          $sub
                        );
                      }
                      return $where;
                    }
                    add_filter( 'movies_where' , 'restrict_by_first_letter', 1 , 2 );

                    $results = new WP_Query( $args );

                ?>

                <table width="100%"><!-- #### TABLE #### -->

                    <?php

                        var_dump($results->request);

                        var_dump(wp_list_pluck($results->movies,'movies_title'));

                    ?>

                    <tr style="border-bottom: thin solid #111;">

                        <td class="movie_genre">    

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table><!-- #### / TABLE #### -->

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            </div><!-- #### / COLUMN #### -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you should be using the `posts_where` filter rather than the `movies_where` that you are specifying. It also looks like you are calling for database data that does not exist. You need to be calling `post_title` in the `$wpdb->posts` table.

I would try updating your code like this:

```
function restrict_by_first_letter( $where, $qry ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sub = $qry->get('substring_where');
    if (!empty($sub)) {
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
        " AND SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 1, 1 ) = %s ", $sub
        );
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'restrict_by_first_letter', 1 , 2 );
```

I would also move this code (the part of the code I copied into this answer) to `functions.php`.

Comment: thanks for your input, but I did as you said and I got this result..string(264) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'movies' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND SUBSTRING( .movies_title, 1, 1 ) = 'T' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10" array(0) { } 
 title-t

Comment: I updated my answer. It also looks like you were calling some database data that does not exist.

Comment: ok I have updated my code and now I have gotten it to echo the title as hyperlink but its just echoing the word array but the hyperlink works :/,...<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo wp_list_pluck($query->posts,'posts_title'); ?></a>

Comment: worked out the title ..<?php $post = get_post($post_id); $title = $post->post_title; ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>